# How to access a particular field of other document which is in some "abc" Collection from some other "xyz" Collection in Firestore Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck in between of a flutter project, can someone please help me in solving this issue?For this project I'm using firestore as a database.

**Quick Summary of the project :**
one app - > Two different account types.(say it as **student** and **tutor**)

tutor - generates a QR code. ( whenever QR code is generated, a field named  as "TotalClassesTook" is created and maintains a value which is the number of QR codes generated by that particular tutor)

student - scans the QR code.( whenever QR code is scanned, a field named as "TotalClassesAttended" is created and maintains a value which is the number of QR codes scanned)

**My Requirement Now :**
Now in the student account type(which is in "Students" collection), how can i get the"TotalClassesTook" field values(which is in different collection named as "Tutors") and calculate attendance percentage for that particular student and display it in the student account?

Please let me know the way if that's possible

**FireStore Structure of project**

[image: Students]

[image: Tutors]

Comment: Post how your firebase looks like, mention the exact fields that you want to access, and it'd be easier to help out :)

Comment: @Guthaifa Muayyad I have attached the image please check it once, and i  want to get the "totalClassesTook" field value which is in "tutors" collection while staying in the "students" collection.

Comment: Thanks, please also post the 'Tutors" collection, to see how you are storing the data references.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad added that too. Please let me know if any way out there

Comment: I think your logic is flawed, there is no link between tutor and student in the structure you shared, other than tutorid in the student collection which is null, so how are you suppose to know which tutor document to look for per each student? Can you share some of your code that you already developed to atempt this action? This will help to see if you are with a wrong logic.

Comment: @Rafael Lemos yes you are right, That's why I'm confused i have no clue how to do that. Is there any way you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, I think your logic is flawed, there is no link between tutor and student in the structure you shared, other than `tutorid` in the student collection which is null, so there is no way to know which tutor document to look for per each student.

Although you should come up with a solution to this yourself as only you will know what are the requirements of your app, I can give you some insights in how I would do this:

First you need to create a link between a student and all the tutors, assuming that a tutor can only teach one class (and if this not true you can create a second identifier like classname of something like that) you could create a subcollection of student where each subdocument will act like a student information for that specific class, so you will have this structure:

```
students Collection
    email
    fullName
    mobileNumber
    role
    rollNumber
    studentClass Subcolletion
        tutorId
        totalClassesAttended
        present
```

At this point you can get the StudentClass document's `totalClassesAttended` to calculate the attendence like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                 .collection('students')
                 .doc('YOUR_STUDENT_ID')
                 .collection('studentClass')
                 .where('tutorId', isEqualTo: 'YOUR_TUTOR_ID')
                 .get()
                 .then((snapshot) {
                     //this will be the value you want
                     String classesAttended = snapshot.data['totalClassesAttended'].toString();
                 });
```